# VBA set file date modified and read it from c#

Tags: c#, vba, excel

I am trying to get the correct date within my C# program of the file that I am saving in VBA.

This is my code in VBA that sets a cell to the date and then saves the worksheet.

```vb
Sheets("KeepTrackSecret").Range(tagNumRange).Value = Format(Now(), "MM/dd/yyyy hh:mm AM/PM")

newFileName = objFolders("desktop")
Randomize
newFileName = newFileName & "\BOM_" & CLng(Rnd() * 999999999) & ".xlsx"
Application.DisplayAlerts = False
ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs newFileName, FileFormat:=51, CreateBackup:=False
Call unlockSheets(False)
ActiveWorkbook.Close SaveChanges:=False
Application.DisplayAlerts = True
```

So the above code works just fine. It places the current date into a cell:

[image]

And the file info looks like this:

[image]

As you can see, both match up just fine.

So now I use some C# code in order to read the cell value from the excel file:

```csharp
private bool checkExcelFile(string orgPath)
{
    var path = string.Format("{0}\\{1}", pathString, importData);

    FileInfo fileInfo = new FileInfo(path);

    DateTime creationTime = fileInfo.CreationTime;
    DateTime lastWriteTime = fileInfo.LastWriteTime;
    DateTime lastAccessTime = fileInfo.LastAccessTime;
    DateTime creationTimeUtc = fileInfo.CreationTimeUtc;
    DateTime lastWriteTimeUtc = fileInfo.LastWriteTimeUtc;
    DateTime lastAccessTimeUtc = fileInfo.LastAccessTimeUtc;

    string strLastModified = System.IO.File.GetLastWriteTime(path).ToString("MM/dd/yyyy hh:mm tt");
    string blah = System.IO.File.GetLastWriteTime(path).ToString("MM/dd/yyyy hh:mm tt");

    DateTime result = Convert.ToDateTime(excel.checkingFile(path));
}

public string checkingFile(string path)
{
    FileInfo newFile = new FileInfo(path);
    ExcelPackage pck = new ExcelPackage(newFile);
    var ws = pck.Workbook.Worksheets["KeepTrackSecret"];
    string hiddenDate = ws.Cells["A1"].Text; ;

    return hiddenDate;
}
```

The values I get are the following:

> ```
>      creationTime: 10/10/2017 10:40:35 AM
>
>     lastWriteTime: 10/10/2017 10:40:35 AM
>
>    lastAccessTime: 10/10/2017 10:40:35 AM
>
>   creationTimeUtc: 10/10/2017 2:40:35 PM
>
>  lastWriteTimeUtc: 10/10/2017 2:40:35 PM
>
> lastAccessTimeUtc: 10/10/2017 2:40:35 PM
>
>   strLastModified: 10/10/2017 10:40 AM
>
>              blah: 10/10/2017 10:40 AM
>
>            result: 10/10/2017 10:38:00 AM
> ```

As you see I come up with many different times when looking at the file. The **result** is the correct datetime since its getting that from the excel cell. But all the others do not match it. Its either too high or just completely way off.

What would I be doing incorrectly in order to fix it so that both datetimes will be correct?

Comment: All of those are properties of the file itself, generated by the system clock at various points.  If you wrote the date to a cell, then 2 minutes later saved the document, then that explains some disparities.  Some of these can be much later if someone reopened the file?

Comment: Its all saved at the same time.

Comment: Are you saving to a local machine or out to a network?  One time I worked on a Novell network and the times would be drastically off from my local, windows machine.

Comment: Local machine @JimmySmith

Comment: Just grasping at straws but try adding `fileinfo.Refresh;`  above `DateTime creationTime = fileInfo.CreationTime;` and let me know if the times are getting more accurate.

Comment: Same output @JimmySmith